# Adding a custom object to NIB in XCode 4.1 is way too much complicated compared to 3.2

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder, custom-controls, nib, xcode3.2

In XCode 3.2, IB has a **Classes** tab in the Library to let you add your own class to nib file. But in XCode 4.1 that tab is disappeared. There is an item called "Custom Objects" in object library but I never figure out how to use it.

So in XCode 4.1 if I want to add my own class to nib I have to drag general object then change it in Identity inspector. Way too much complicated and not straightforward at all.

Anyone knows why xcode 4.1 introduced this change ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way things work is the more simple something is, the less customization you can do. I agree I dislike the new IB, although it does make room for more customization.

Comment: So what customization you were talking about regarding the new IB ?